# Javascript document.getElementsByName() function is being weird at me

Tags: javascript

I've got the following variables in my simple javascript calculator:

```
var distance = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("distance"), 10);
var mins_running = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("mins_running").value, 10);  // the running pace minutes
var secs_running = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("secs_running").value, 10);  //    the running pace seconds
var mins_walking = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("mins_walking").value, 10);  // the walking pace minutes
var secs_walking = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("secs_walking").value, 10);  // the walking pace seconds
```

The problem is, when I try to use these variables (entered as text from a form but meant to be used as numbers in the calculator).  When I do a typeof() in the developer console.log I'm told the values are of type 'number', but the *very next line* is also a console.log('mins_running'), for example, and it explicitly states the value is "NaN".  Is my value a number or not?  What's going on?  Stupid javascript--be more normal, darn it!

Any reasonable input/help will be appreciated.

Thanks for all the help, guys.  Looks like I'm back to using the old Form.elementName.value thing instead.  (if this is a really bad idea or just not good for production code at all, please feel free to say something.)

Comment: `typeof(NaN) === "number"`, so at least that bit is "normal" :)

Comment: *"Stupid javascript--be more normal, darn it!"* The fault, dear user, is not in our languages, but in ourselves...

Comment: *"When I do a typeof() in the developer console.log I'm told the values are of type 'number'"* Yes. `NaN`, name notwithstanding, is of type `"number"`. (Try `console.log(typeof NaN)`).

Comment: Stop blaming the "javascript" and start learning about this great language. Also don't forget to read [Javascript: The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html) by Douglas Crockford

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementsByName("mins_running")
```

returns a `NodeList`, which has no attribute `value`. Use

```
document.getElementsByName("mins_running")[0].value
```

instead.

Example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="mins_running" value="10">
<br><button id="theButton">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
  // Note we're getting the first match ----------------vvv
  var field = document.getElementsByName("mins_running")[0];
  display("The field's current value is: " +
          parseInt(field.value, 10));
  // And using its value-^^^^^
};

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/olukit/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/olukit/1/edit)

Comment: That gives me a typeerror.  The mins_running element on the form is the name of a single text box, not a group, if it helps to know that.

Comment: @user1419715: It doesn't matter that there's only one match, `getElementsByName` always returns a list. If there's only one match, the list only has one element. It's not like this [isn't clearly documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259).

Comment: @user1419715: I've added a demonstration to Waleed's answer (not that the answer wasn't clear).

Answer (score 1):

[Waleed shared how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015375/31671).

The technical reason why you got `NaN` there is...

You grab a reference to a `NodeList` with `document.getElementsByName("distance")`, and you attempt to access the property `value` on that. That property does not exist on `NodeList`, or anywhere on the prototype chain. In JavaScript, that means `undefined` is returned.

When you call `parseInt()` with `undefined` as the first argument, the function will `toString()` it and return `"undefined"`. You explicitly set the base as `10`, which obviously only covers digits `0` to `9`, and the number can't be parsed. When this happens, `parseInt()` returns `NaN`. Since `NaN` is of the `Number` type (it's part of the IEEE-754 specification), the `typeof` operator tells you it's a `"Number"`.

If you'd set the base as `31`, it'd be able to parse `"undefined"`, and it'd be `26231474015353` :)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm using getElementsByName because I've been told it's a best-practice for gleaning data from web forms--did I misinterpret or was I misinformed? I originally tried using it without the .value because when I got errors I thought maybe getElementsByName returned an object.

Comment: @user1419715 It's a fine tool for grabbing form elements, which generally always have a `name` attribute for server side processing, so you get an identifier *for free*. Just worth keeping in mind they return a `NodeList`, not a direct reference to an element like `getElementById()`.

Answer (score -1):

Set ids for your tags and use getElementById instead.